# Java Eclipse suggests that I make my method static

Tags: java, arraylist, static, package

I have the classes `Player`, `PoliticCard` and `ModelPlayer`. Both `Player` and `PoliticCard` have an `ArrayList` to store color values from the `enum Color`. I want to write the method `DrawCard()` that takes a `Color` value from the `ArrayList` of `PoliticCard` and stores it in the `ArrayList` of `Player`.

Eclipse made me change the `ArrayList` of `PoliticCard` to `static` but in every other post I've seen `static` is only used for constants which is not the case here (the `ArrayList` in `PoliticCard` is gonna change constantly every time each player uses the method `DrawCard()`) so is having a static `ArrayList` in `PoliticCard` gonna be a problem here?

PS: All the classes are in different packages (of course i have imported them all when needed), it has something to do with this?

```
public enum Color {
    RED, GREEN
}

public class PoliticCard {
    private Color cardColor;
    private static ArrayList<Color> politicCards;

    public PoliticCard() {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 13) {
            politicCards.add(Color.RED);
            i++;
        }
        while (i < 26) {
            politicCards.add(Color.GREEN);
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Color> getPoliticCards() {
        return politicCards;
    }

}

public class Player {
    private int id;
    private ArrayList<Color> politicCards;

    public Player(int id) {
        this.setId(id);
    }

    public ArrayList<Color> getPoliticCards() {
        return politicCards;
    }
}

public class ModelPlayer {
    public void Player(Player player) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10) {
            new Player(i);
        }

    }

    public void DrawCard(Player player) {
        int i = 0;
        if (PoliticCard.getPoliticCards().get(i) != null) {
            player.getPoliticCards().add(PoliticCard.getPoliticCards().get(i));
            PoliticCard.getPoliticCards().remove(i);
        } else {
            i++;
            player.getPoliticCards().add(PoliticCard.getPoliticCards().get(i));
            PoliticCard.getPoliticCards().remove(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `final` instead of `static`? Also, *please* format your code before posting - it's really hard to read at the moment.

Comment: If you want the list to be an instance variable (non-static), then you need a `PoliticCard` _instance_ for accessing it. Currently you're accessing the list through static context / class name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Eclipse made me change the arrayList of PoliticCard to static

It wasn't the Eclipse that have forced you to change to static it was the Java Compiler. And the reason behind this is this line in your DrawCard method:

```
PoliticCard.getPoliticCards().remove(i);
```

You are trying to access getter for politics cards using class PoliticCard instead of instance of PoliticCard. And that's why both getter and the field must be static.